# R subset of rows based on comparing two date fields where one is less than

Tags: r, date, compare, as.date

Brand new at R.

I have a table of data with two date fields:
ReportingPeriodStart
Classdate

I need two data sets: those rows where ReportingPeriodStart is less than Classdate and one where Reportingperiodstart is greater than Classdate.

I thought I might be able to do something like this:

```
PreStuff <- subset(boost, REPORTINGPERIODENDDATE < WaveStart, 
select = c(PROVIDERNAME,DEPARTMENT,SPECIALTY,
REPORTINGPERIODENDDATE,WaveStart TOSH,TOUD,TIMEINSYS,SEVENASEVENP,PJTIME,PROFSCORE)
)
```

but I'm getting the `error:  unexpected symbol in "prestuff ...."`

I've looked through similar posts but each of those has a dataset that's a list of hardwired dates. I have two date fields I have to compare.

I just got R installed a few days ago and am able to use the `plot(x,y)` function basically.

How would one go about grabbing those rows where one datefield is less than another date field?

Comment: Check out the 'lubridate' package, it makes working with dates easy.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: Thanks for the referral to the page about making a good post. I don't understand any of it unfortunately. It will take me awhile to figure out what it all means. In the meantime, I have a table with three columns:

Name Date1 Date2

I need to make two sets of data from this table: 
All the rows where Date1 is less than date2 and all the rows where Date1 is greater than date2.

I've tried using Date1 < Date2, but I believe the error I'm getting means the less than symbol doesn't work. 

So I tried Lubridate and taking the difference and looking for difference <0 or difference >0.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the select statement. Specifically quotes and `WAVESTART TOSH` where most likely forgot a comma, or are dealing with implicit conversion. See the help:

> The select argument exists only for the methods for data frames and
>   matrices. It works by first replacing column names in the selection
>   expression with the corresponding column numbers in the data frame and
>   then using the resulting integer vector to index the columns. This
>   allows the use of the standard indexing conventions so that for
>   example ranges of columns can be specified easily, or single columns
>   can be dropped (see the examples).

So

1. You have to pass a vector of character arguments to reference the column names for select. Try `c("PROVIDERNAME", ...` instead of `c(PROVIDERNAME, ...`). Or else R will start looking for a vector logicals or characters called `PROVIDERNAME` in the workspace to get the indices.
2. You have a column name with a space `WaveStart TOSH`. This is giving you the actual error. In matrices you can store column names with a space. But if you reference columns by character, `R` will either convert them to `data.frame` first or ask you to do it. In this case, `as.data.frame.matrix` would change `WaveStart TOSH` to `WaveStart.TOSH`... or you just forgot a comma.